# How to add second link to script in JqueryWidget code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a widget and it works great, but right now I am giving my users a link to a **remote** script, a link to **my** script and a div to place on their page.  I would like to reduce this to just a link to **my** script and the div.  The remote link I want to include in my code below is

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can anyone please educate me on how to add a second link in my code?  I already link to a remote jquery and a remote stylesheet, but I am not sure how/where to include another remote link.  I have tried a number of places and ways, but I keep breaking my page, haha.  **Thanks** for any help offered.

```
(function() {
    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;
    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.12.4') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src", "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
            script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                    scriptLoadHandler();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }
    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
            // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
            // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
            jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
            // Call our main function
            main();
        }
        /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            /******* Load CSS *******/
            var css_link = $("<link>", {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');
            /******* Load HTML *******/
            var jsonURL = "//www.myurl.com/mssql.php/ws_nfy";
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: jsonURL,
                    success: searchCallback
                });
            });
            function searchCallback(data) {
                var ws_nfy = data.ws_nfy.records;
                jQuery.each(ws_nfy, function(index, nfy) {
                    jQuery("#tabs ul").append('<li><a href="#tabs-' + nfy[0] + '">' + nfy[2] + '</a></li>');
                    jQuery("#tabs ul").after("<div id='tabs-" + nfy[0] + "'>" + nfy[1] + "</div>");
                });
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            };
        });
    }
})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

Comment: `but I keep breaking my page` What exactly are you breaking? Do you get errors in the `console`? If I remove the part of the search (because it's not really the url, it works (I mean, no errors).. http://jsbin.com/qezejik/edit?html,js

Comment: Yes, the errors have been caused by placing code in the wrong place.  For example, I tried to duplicate the three script tags and I put those below the original, then I tried to add the script via document.write and append to the head, placed that in a number of areas without success.  I also tried to duplicate the Load CSS area and make that a Load Script - that didn't work either...  I don't know enough about JQuery yet to know where proper placement would be and which syntax I should be using...

Comment: Do you have a public URL so I could see the errors?

Comment: There are no errors now, the code works fine, I was just looking to see if someone could tell me where/how to place the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> link into this working code...

Comment: *«There are no errors now»*... Is the question resolved? --- You should check if the jQuery-ui library is already loaded too. Because loading it a second time will cause issues.

Comment: The code above works, but I need to add a second link to a remote js - the first one links to the jquery code, the second one (jQuery-ui.js) links to the tabbed widget code, I need both.  My question is, how/where do I add a link to a second external js?  I am very new, so this is probably something very simple, I just don't know how to do it and have been unable to figure it out on my own...  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if jQuery is already loaded before injecting it... Which is good. Now you should do the same for jQuery-UI.

So that's the same procedure...

Try this:

```
(function() {
  // Localize jQuery variable
  var jQuery;
  /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
  if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.12.4') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        // For old versions of IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
        }
      };
    } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
  } else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    //main();                   // Not now! Check for UI first.
    checkUI();
  }
  /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
  function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    //main();               // Not now! Check for UI first.
    checkUI();
  }

        // ========================== Check if jQuery-UI is already loaded    
  function checkUI(){
    if(typeof(jQuery.ui) != "undefined"){
      // UI is loaded already.
      console.log("UI is defined");
      console.log( typeof(jQuery.ui) );
      main();

    }else{
      // UI is not loaded. Got to load it.
      console.log("UI is NOT defined");
      //console.log( typeof(jQuery.ui) );

      var ui = document.createElement('script');
      ui.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

      // For UI
      window.$ = jQuery;

      ui.setAttribute("src", "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js");
      console.log(ui);



      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ui);

      if (ui.readyState) {
        console.log( "READYSTATE" );
        ui.onreadystatechange = function() { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
            console.log( "STATELOADED" );
            main();
          }
        };
      } else {
        console.log( "ELSE" );
        jQuery(ui).on("load", function(){
          console.log("UI loaded...");
          main();
        });
      }
    }
  }



  /******** Our main function ********/
  function main() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      console.log("jQuery: "+jQuery.fn.jquery+"\njQuery-UI: "+jQuery.ui);
      console.log("Tabs element: "+jQuery("#tabs").length);
      /******* Load CSS *******/
      var css_link = $("<link>", {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href: "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
      });
      css_link.appendTo('head');
      /******* Load HTML *******/
      var jsonURL = "//www.myurl.com/api.php/ws_nfy";
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: jsonURL,
        success: searchCallback
      });
      function searchCallback(data) {
        var ws_nfy = data.ws_nfy.records;
        jQuery.each(ws_nfy, function(index, nfy) {
          jQuery("#tabs ul").append('<li><a href="#tabs-' + nfy[0] + '">' + nfy[2] + '</a></li>');
          jQuery("#tabs ul").after("<div id='tabs-" + nfy[0] + "'>" + nfy[1] + "</div>");
        });
        jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
      };
    });
  }
})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing - not loading the main until checking for the 2nd links existence.  If it exists, load main, else load the ui.js then main...  That makes sense and seeing it laid out makes it easier to understand.  Thank you for that.  I replace my code with this, but I am getting an error... ReferenceError: jquery is not defined - so that means that the first script to JQuery isn't getting loaded, right?

Comment: Hew... No. That mean I made a mistake about the capital Q in jQuery in `if(jquery.ui){` I edited.

Comment: LoL - see, I should probably have been able to see that, I'm too new! :)  It is closer, the tabs come up with the content, but the formatting is missing... the error is TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function...

Comment: No, not that either: TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function

Comment: mmm... Maybe the check condition isn't correct. Try `if(typeof(jQuery.ui) != "undefined")`

Comment: same error: TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function - do you think this could have anything to do with the noConflict line?

Comment: Add this in ready : `console.log("jQuery: "+jQuery.fn.jquery+"\njQuery-UI: "+jQuery.ui);`

Comment: Ha.. And `console.log("Tabs element: "+jQuery("#tabs").length);` too ;)

Comment: There are two lines with ready and I am showing my ignorance here, but I am not sure where to put the code... :(  Sorry, I am trying to keep up :)

Comment: Haa... I didn't see that. Within the first. The second is useless by the way, you can remove it. (BUT! keep the inner Ajax!!!)

Comment: OK, I updated the code above so you could see what I have added... still getting the same error...

Comment: Ok... And what is the output of the console.log lines ?

Comment: I hope this is what you mean:
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function
    at Object.searchCallback [as success] (nfy.js:87)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154626/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-user1255154).